# C++ STL low level programming

Tags: c++, boost, stl, operating-system

Is it possible to do some low level programming with STL, at least containers and algorithms? I need to do a simple OS and have to know if is feasible to try the C++ and STL or go with plain C. Any resources are accepted.Thanks.

Edit---------

And how about Boost?

Comment: Nothing wrong with using even the most complex framework, except one small thing... performance, but if perf is not an issue, you can as well go with java. Regards.

Comment: @BigMike, true, but I wouldn't consider the STL to be a complex framework. Some vendors offer very efficient implementations.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y I was referring to every kind of framework out there (like .NET or similars) :)

Comment: Performance isn't the reason such large frameworks are rarely seen in kernels. The real problem is that the kernel is usually a pretty barren environment. You're operating outside the CPU's virtual memory, which removes a lot of invariants and safeguards. And you don't have all the OS services and APIs available to rely on. So it is simply more work to implement such frameworks to run in the kernel, and even if you do it, the added complexity is dangerous because a bug in the kernel can do much more damage than a bug in usermode software. With kernels it is very much KISS.

Comment: Why do you limit your choice to "C++ and STL" or "C"? Even if the datastructures in the common libraries would be the wrong choice for you and your requirements, what is wrong with choosing C++ and make at least use of the core language features and abstraction mechanisms to build your own specialized datastructures?

Comment: "_low level programming_" Low level WRT what?

Comment: @curiousguy i need to implement some data structures and algorithms for task and memory management. dynamic memory alocation(aka new) is not  implemented(because is a os service), i wanted to ease my life with the help of STL data structures and algorithms but they mostly rely on dynamic alocation so i asked if someone knows how to do it correctly and as easy as possible.

Comment: "_dynamic memory alocation(aka new) is not implemented(because is a os service),_" I don't understand. Why wouldn't you use `new` in a kernel?

Comment: @jalf "_You're operating outside the CPU's virtual memory, which removes a lot of invariants_" like what?

Comment: @curiousguy because when someone uses the new operator in C++ in fact it calls for the kernel(memory management system which is a component of the kernel) which allocates memory on the heap for the process. Heap is a data structure managed by OS. so at the first stage i must implement the memory allocation system and i cannot use STL containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should totally use the C++ STL. Even if you only work with bare pointers and arrays, the STL Algorithms will vastly clarify your thinking and programming. The genius of Alexander Stepanov's STL is that Algorithms are expressed with respect to Iterators, and Iterators are a generalization of pointers, so you can apply any of his algorithms to raw pointers and arrays with zero run-time overheard.

Plus, here's the best part. If you think like Alexander Stepanov, and use his pointer-to-beginning and pointer-to-past-the-end idiom, all of the plus one (+ 1) and minus one (- 1) terms will drop out of your array and loop logic and you'll never again have to watch out for off-by-one logic errors.

You should write an OS that natively represents strings as a pair of byte* to begin and past-the-end of a UTF8 memory block. Then your OS can replace the Unices and liberate us from null-terminated signed char* strings.

Comment: Yep, i have big plans for my toy OS :D. I forgot that algorithms can be used with raw pointers. My focus was on the containers but i guess i can live without them until i implement the runtime and dynamic memory allocation, till then algorithms will be a great help for me. Thanks, i guess i need to refresh my C++ skills, because a lot of stupid questions come into my head lately.

Answer (score 2):

Most implementations of the C++ STL I'm familiar with have been significantly dependent on an OS (particularly for memory allocation). I'm not going to rule out using the C++ STL in an operating system kernel, but you'd have to do a lot of work to port an implementation of the STL to your environment (e.g, implement a memory allocator, make exception handling work, write an iostreams compatibility shim to output to the screen/TTY/whatever), and to get a compiler to target your implementation correctly. It may be less work overall to just write the OS in C. :)

Comment: The STL Should be using the global `operator new` which you can define/overload on your own. Alternately you could even use custom allocators for your containers. If your vendor STL doesn't support this then it is simply broken.

Comment: Similarly the standard streams, like `cout` are declared as `extern` so that you can define them however you'd like.  Here is where however you'll have to start linker juggling.  Of course, you could simply avoid using certain streams.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: None of STL uses `operator new`. All of the STL containers have allocators, which you can use to manage memory however you like.

Comment: Is there some reason why you couldn't just use a specialized `std::allocator` with your containers and still be able to leverage STL? I mean, you must have some form of memory management if you're able to allocate memory at all. So if it makes sense, why not?

Comment: @NicolBolas, correct, but in turn the standard allocator is required to use the global new operator. 20.6.9.1-6 _the storage is obtained by calling `::operator new(std::size_t)`_

Comment: Clarification: By "implement a memory allocator" I mean the low-level process of carving out some memory, not implementing `std::allocator`. This isn't necessarily trivial when you're on bare metal and don't have access to things like `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can (and should) use C++ for an OS.  Depending on where in the OS
the code occurs, you might have to forgo parts (or all) of the standard
library, and in some cases perhaps, even some functionality
(exceptions?); it all depends on the context.

With regards to the STL containers, they would certainly be usable at
some levels, provided you specify custom allocators.  (The library
implementation of `operator new` will depend on OS functionality, so
probably won't be available in the OS itself.  Although even this
depends on the design of the OS.)  And there should be no problem with
most of the algorithms.